# How to add error information empty field and redirect after login in ReactJS and Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I use react js, react-router, and firebase database. and I want to add error information if login field is empty and if success I want to redirect to dashboard, but it doesn't work

this code in router.js

```
 <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Simple}>
    <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/dashboard" name="Home" component={Full}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
    </Route>
```

this code in login.js

```
    function setErrorMsg(error) {
      return {
        loginMessage: error
      }
    }

    class Login extends Component {
       state = { loginMessage: null }
      handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        login(this.email.value, this.password.value)
          .catch((error) => {
              this.setState(setErrorMsg('Invalid username/password.'))
            })
      }
      resetPassword = () => {
        resetPassword(this.email.value)
          .then(() => this.setState(setErrorMsg(`Password reset email sent to ${this.email.value}.`)))
          .catch((error) => this.setState(setErrorMsg(`Email address not found.`)))
      }
      render() {
        return (
         <h1>Login</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
          <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-user"></i></span>
          <input type="text" ref={(email) => this.email = email} className="form-control"  placeholder="Email"/>
           </div>
          <div className="input-group mb-4">
          <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-lock"></i></span>
         <input type="password" ref={(password) => this.password = password} className="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
         </div>
         {
            this.state.loginMessage &&
            <div>
            <span className="sr-only">Error:</span>
             &nbsp;{this.state.loginMessage} <a href="#" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="alert-link">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
         }
         <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
         <button type="button" className="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>

   </form>

    );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought is that you need to bind your onSubmit, like `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>`.

Using `class ... extends` doesn't do autobinding.

Another way I like to do it is to bind in my contructor function:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
// your code here
}
```